# android 2.2 JAR source not found

Tags: android, sql, jar, executable-jar

I get this error when ever i try run a rawQuery statement for my android application. Does anyone no how to fix it?

I am using android 2.2 for my SDK
[image: Cannot get JAR source]

its driving me crazy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niall,

The Android source code isn't included with the SDK.  I believe this guide will show you how to add browse-able source to eclipse: http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html